# Swing Indeterminate JProgressBar moving too fast

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I have created a Swing JProgresBar and set indeterminate to "true". The progress bar works correctly but it cycles extremely fast and the it's annoying to look at for longer than 3 seconds. I want to slow it down and I thought there would be a method for this. If there is a method I haven't found it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sftpProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
sftpDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code about how you are doing that?

Comment: This is pretty much it. I used the Swing Design Window to construct the UI. Here is what I do to display and set it to indeterminate.
        sftpProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        sftpDialog.setVisible(true);

I apologize in advance for the code formatting. Not sure how to do that in the comments on here.

Comment: *"code formatting. Not sure how to do that in the comments on here."*  **Don't** put code in comments.  Edit it back into the question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've edited the question and added the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the animation speed of a JProgressBar. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/swing/1.4/pb.html):

> The "ProgressBar.cycleTime" UI default lets look and feel implementers (as well as other developers)specify how many milliseconds each animation cycle takes. For example, a cycle time of 500 means that the indeterminate-mode progress bar animation repeats twice per second.

Comment: I tried using cycleTime but it did not come up as a method I could use. Maybe it's a different type of progress bar?

Comment: @Conner As far as I know there is only one progressbar in Swing and thats the JProgressBar. Maybe the values are being overridden by the selected Look and Feel (Nimbus, Metal, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I fixed the problem. In "main" there was some generated code that I commented out. The only thing that changed was the progress bar. It slowed down to a much slower and more visibly pleasing speed. This is the code I commented out.

```
try {
  for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info :  javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIManager.put("ProgressBar.repaintInterval", new Integer(250));
 UIManager.put("ProgressBar.cycleTime", new Integer(6000));
```

*ProgressBar.cycleTime*: is the parameter using you can specify how many milliseconds each animation cycle takes
. You can refer details in [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/pb.html)